# How do I add a pointer to my XR Interactor line visual?

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting, oculus

I am setting up my project with XR Interaction toolkit. As usual, there are two red rays from the controllers after the set up as shown below.

[image]

However, I want the rays to appear exactly as it is in the image below.

[image]

The rays will be short and when I point to an object, a pointer appears like I have in the below image. I have played around with the **XR Interactor Line visual**. I was able to reduce the length and width of the rays but the pointer isn't there for interacting with objects.

Another attempt I made was to add **XR Interactor Reticle Visual** component to my controller. I then added sphere prefab to the **reticle prefab**. It looked like want I want but also could not interact with buttons like the normal ray would.

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the collider from the sphere prefab you used for the reticle?

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually, I was not able to add the sphere prefab to the reticle without removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out too a couple of days back and just felt I should write how I did it.

If you don't already have an **XR Interactor Line Visual** component added to your controller, add it. I reduced the **Line Width**, Changed the **Color Gradient** to white and **Invalid Color Gradient**  to grey, I also changed the **Line Length**.

For the **Reticle**, I created a **sphere** gameObject on my scene, removed the **sphere collider**, dragged it to my material, reduced the scale to **0.03** in all dimensions. If it doesn't work after this, change the sphere's Material to **_defaultMat**.